Kubernetes cannot find path for running container. Docker-compose works fine with the same image
I'm trying to deploy nestjs application using Google Cloud and Kubernetes. When running the container from a pod I get the following error:
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1215
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/app/dist/apps/movies/main'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:15)  
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1038:27)
    at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:212:19)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:158:5)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:30:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

When using docker-compose to run the same image, everything works fine.
Dockerfile
FROM node:alpine As development

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json tsconfig.json
COPY nest-cli.json nest-cli.json

RUN npm install

COPY apps/movies apps/movies
COPY libs libs

RUN npm run build movies

FROM node:alpine As production 

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install --prod

COPY --from=development /app/dist ./dist

CMD ["node", "dist/apps/movies/main"]

deployment.yaml file
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: movies
  name: movies
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: movies
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: movies
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/cinema-426911/movies/production-base
          name: movies

docker-compose file
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 2345:5432
  movies:
    image: europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/cinema-426911/movies/production-base
    command: node dist/apps/movies/main
    environment:
      - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    volumes:
      - .:/app

Do you have any idea what might be the reason for the error?
............................................................................

In your Compose file, you hide the image content with volumes:, and you override the default command:.  Neither of these are happening in the Kubernetes setup.  If you delete these overrides so the local Docker setup is running what's actually in your image, do you get the same result?
